# Fragment onCreate() issue

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i need to declare my Chronometer on onCreate() of my fragment because if I declare on onCreateView(), every time the ChronometerFragment is called the Chronometer is reseted.

My actual code:

**ChronometerFragment.class**

```
public class CronometroFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btStart, btPause, btReset;
    boolean click;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cronometro, container,
                false);

        final Cronometro cronometro = (Cronometro) v.findViewById(R.id.cronometro);

        click = true;

        btStart = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btStart);
        btPause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btPause);
        btReset = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btReset);

        btStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cronometro.start();
            }
        });

        btPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cronometro.pause();
            }
        });

        btReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                cronometro.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                cronometro.stop();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

**fragment_cronometro.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_cronometro"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Timer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.hello.app.Cronometro
            android:id="@+id/cronometro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="45sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btStart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_start" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/PauseStop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btPause"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_pause" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btReset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_reset" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is that user cannot change fragment because this reset the Chronometer.

Please, can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is badly formulated.. But in your onCreate, put setretaininstance(true). This should work. :-)

Comment: Hello, i put setretaininstance(true) but i cant put the cronometro to onCreate because i need associate it with the viewId and i cant acess the cronometro variable in the Buttons click

Comment: But if you've put setretaininstance in your onCreate, that should be sufficient? Or maybe i dont understand your question right?

Comment: Ahh. Now i see what you want. Ok, so for this to work you will need to save the state of the cronometer and then when the view reloads, re-set the state. Keep setretaininstance in onCreate.

Comment: Well that depends on how your cronometro class looks. But the easiest way wold be to store the current run-time in your fragment and then re-set it when the view is reset.